# Method in Controller not being triggered by call in View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method within my controller that simply counts the number of patients a user has. I tested out the query and it works as expected when I manually pass in a user_id (not passing in the helper method from devise : current_user). However, when I try call the method from my View the method does not get called, I added in a print out statement just to see if it is just my query not being executed however my logs confirm that not even the print out statement is being invoked.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

**patient_controller.rb**

```
helper_method :counter_patients

 def counter_patients
      puts "Tiggered"
      patient_user_counter = Patient.where(user_id: current_use).select(:user_id).count
  end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<p> Count : <%= @counter_patients %> <p>
```

**Log from Rails Console when running query**

```
irb(main):015:0> r = Patient.where(user_id: 2).select(:user_id).count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT("patients"."user_id") FROM "patients" WHERE "patients"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 2]]
=> 7
```

Comment: `counter_patients != @counter_patients`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view, you insert `<%= @counter_patients %>` which calls the instance variable `@counter_patients`.

But you actually want to call the method `counter_patients` (note the missing `@`).

Change that line in your code to:

```
<p> Count : <%= counter_patients %> <p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, when I make the change I get the following error : undefined local variable or method `counter_patients' for #<#<Class:0x00007f80b5385828>:0x00007f80b537e708>

Comment: Fixed my error, problem was that I was calling the method from another controller that was not serving the page. Thanks for the above as I would be ages trying to fix this!